# List of Bitcoin exchanges available in 2009

Tags: bitcoin-core, blockchain, wallet, decentralized-exchanges

hope you can help. I am helping a friend to find their Bitcoin wallet. The wallet is believed to have been created in 2009 and the coins were transferred to a Bitcoin exchange.

My question is what exchanges were available back then?

My friend said that she has looked into the hacked bitcoin exchanges and claimed that she doesn’t believe her coins were lost on any of those exchanges, although she said Mt Gox looked familiar but that was not the exchange that the Bitcoins were transferred to.

Thank you in advance for the responses.

Answer (score 1):

It seems there were no exchanges available in 2009.

According to [cryptohopper](https://www.cryptohopper.com/blog/what-was-the-first-crypto-exchange-449)

> On March 17, 2010 Bitcoinmarket, the first cryptocurrency exchange went live.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mt._Gox) says

> On 18 July [2010], Mt. Gox launched its exchange

[Amazon](https://aws.amazon.com/solutions/case-studies/bitstamp/) claim:

> Bitstamp is the world’s oldest cryptocurrency exchange. [...]
> Bitstamp was founded by Nejc Kodrič and Damijan Merlak in [August] 2011.

I guess Bitstamp is the oldest *surviving* Bitcoin exchange. So any money in exchanges created earlier than that is presumably lost to any account holders.