# What were the most popular bitcoin mining softwares, services or platforms in or before january 2010?

Tags: mining-pools, mining-reward

My friend who died few weeks back, He claimed that he mined bitcoin using his personal computer

> back in the days

he said.

But i had a glimpse of an archive he named

> btc.gz

which had file made or modified last in January end of 2010, which made me wonder whether his claims were true.

Now i am curious of how he did it, while trying to profile him.

So were they any free bitcoin mining services, platform or software available by January 2010, please provide possible list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that in January 2010, all miners would have been CPU mining with an early version of Bitcoin core (then called just Bitcoin).

---

Somewhat related: [List of Bitcoin exchanges available in 2009](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/122061/13866)

---

According to [Nicehash's History of Bitcoin Mining](https://www.nicehash.com/blog/post/the-history-of-cryptocurrency-mining)

> The first miner was the official Bitcoin miner.

> It is believed that the first GPU miner was developed by ArtForz, who allegedly mined the first block with his GPU farm on 18th of July, 2010

> In 2012, the first ASIC projects started to emerge

---

The first mining pool appears to be bitcoin.cz which started on 18th September 2010.

---

All the above reinforces the notion that, in or before January 2010, using Nakamoto's Bitcoin software was the only Bitcoin mining software, service or platform.