When Satoshi Nakamoto mined his first set of blocks in 2008/2009, it was on Bitcoin Core, but was he using Linux or Windows?
The question seems anecdotal but it has an importance when reading the old key.MakeNewKey() source code :

At that time, block rewards of 50 BTC were sent to a newly generated pubkey at each blocks. As far I can tell, each key were added to the wallet at the approximately the block’s timestamp.
Bitcoin Core was using /dev/urandom on Linux but on Windows even when openssl was asked for secure randomness, the generator had to be initialized manually each time to a initial value : and in the case of key generation, that value was set to HKEY_PERFORMANCE_DATA by Satoshi !

So if I’m not wrong, this means block rewards mined by using Windows had weak randomness as the possible values are far more limited than the secp256k1’s order.  As a result, does this means he only used Linux personally?

Interesting question. The first released Bitcoin software was only available on Windows so it's safe to assume Satoshi (and anyone else) was using Windows to mine at the time.

@AntoinePoinsot but were Bitcoins actually mined with that version?

Microsoft Windows.
In the Bitcoin v0.1 release announcement Satoshi Nakamoto stated

Windows only for now.  Open source C++ code is included.

Unpack the files into a directory
Run BITCOIN.EXE
It automatically connects to other nodes


Linux versions appeared in 0.2.0 if https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Original_Bitcoin_client is correct

the bitcoin releases 0.1.0 up to 0.1.5 which supported only Windows 2000 / Windows NT and Windows XP (perhaps Windows Vista). The next bitcoin release 0.2.0 from Dec 2009, nearly a year later, starts to support Linux

This is supported by https://www.bitcoin.com/satoshi-archive/forum/bitcoin-forum/21/ and https://satoshi.nakamotoinstitute.org/emails/bitcoin-list/29/

New Features
Martti Malmi
...

Linux version (tested on Ubuntu)



Related questions

When and who coined the term "mining"?
When was the paper of bitcoin announced?
When and how did Bitcoin start?
How did Satoshi Nakamoto create the first Bitcoin? The Genesis Block
What were the most popular bitcoin mining softwares, services or platforms in or before january 2010?
When did Bitcoin Core deprecate the mining function?
When was the first GPU miner made available publicly?
When did the ASIC mining era begin?


But where blocks mined using version 0.1?

Yes. https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/122302/13866

Windows is my opinion because only he would know that.   And to be honest I don't believe Satoshi Nakamoto is even real I believe he was made up by rich people or powerfully people to make a way to hide their money or tax evade.   Or by biblical facts it's to make a one world currency that leads to one world orderc
